# How to not execute hidden forms

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hdcChoose").click(function(){
    $("#hdcNumber").toggle();
    $("#hdcNumber2").hide();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hdcWrite").click(function(){
    $("#hdcNumber").hide();
    $("#hdcNumber2").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

"hdcWrite" and "hdcChoose" are my fields that the user can show or hide. Both consist of a Number that is needed for my SQL query. Here are my SQL WHERE statments:

```
WHERE HDC.NAME ='$hdcChoose'
OR HDC.NAME = '$hdcWrite'");
```

The problem is, that when first field is hidden,and it's not null, it's executed as first in my SQL Query. 
any idea how can I avoid that? Is there any usefull function for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to set the wanted values as "" when the form is clicked. It's very simple:

```
$("#hdcNumber").val("");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `<input type="hidden" id="hdc">` which is filled by the good value when the user click on "hdcWrite" or "hdcChoose" and SQL works with this value.

I thought something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdc">
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hdcChoose").click(function(){
    $("#hdcNumber").toggle();
    $("#hdcNumber2").hide();
    $("#hdc").val($("#hdcNumber").val()); // or $("#hdc").val("hdcNumber");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hdcWrite").click(function(){
    $("#hdcNumber").hide();
    $("#hdcNumber2").toggle();
    $("#hdc").val($("#hdcNumber2").val()); // or $("#hdc").val("hdcNumber2");
  });
});
</script>
```

and SQL would recover the value of the "hdc" like something that:

```
WHERE HDC.NAME ='$hdc'
```

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: How do you transfer your data to SQL?
I thought it was a form, so I suggested you to add a hidden field in the form is treated by SQL, and hidden field would be filled by clicks on "hdcWrite" or "hdcChoose"

Comment: I use session_start() to transfer values.

Comment: I 'd precise my idea, but i'm not sur to understand your problem. Perhaps the Magicianred's solution is better to your problem :)

Comment: You should write a response and validate for those who have the same problem. ;)

Comment: I can't now. My reputation is too low.

Comment: Normally, you can create your answer

Comment: You can help me out, you know, by voting positiv on my commenst and questions.

Comment: I have to wait at least 8 hours before answering my own question.

Answer (score 1):

You can check onsubmit if the field is hidden and empty the value:

```
if($('#hdcChoose').css('display') == 'none')) {
   $('#hdcChoose').val("");
}
```